# strategy/pattern to prevent lost update / race conditions on GAE / memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, concurrency, google-cloud-datastore

Example:

1. Process A - gets the latest version of an entity from memcache
2. Process B - gets the latest version of an entity from memcache
3. Process A - makes some update to the entity retrieved in (1) and then `puts` in db/memcache
4. Process B - makes some update to the entity retrieved in (2) and then `puts` in db/memcache

Update 3. is lost.

What strategy/pattern can be used to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `cas` and `gets` commands:

https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#cas

**EDIT** GAE memcache is actually compatible with memcached. Here's the reference from GAE:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_cas

and final note:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Memcached_compatibility

Comment: Isn't this related to the standalone memcached, not GAE memcache?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the update inside a transaction to make it atomic.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

Comment: Just putting the writes inside a transaction won't improve the situation as it won't stop process B from overwriting A's write.  To prevent you need some sort of lock that A holds, so B won't/can't write, thats where CAS in memcache can help.

Comment: @TimHoffman Datastore transactions protect you exactly from that. See e.g. the simple example https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Uses_for_Transactions . Also, using ndb there's no reason to explicitly cache entities in memcache, as ndb does that for you.

Comment: Of course, if the original question was specifically about memcache, compare and set is the way to go. In my response I spotted the word "db" from the question and assumed datastore is also involved.

Comment: It depends on how you view the OP question.  If you are refering to a series of web views (typical CRUD) - fetch a record, edit in the form, then write back, a simplistic transaction won't prevent the situation described.  Prior to saving the result you now have to read the current state of the record back, compare/resolve conflicts in your edits (ie something you thought you where modifying was changed under you (process B), then decide if you will write it back, or reject the edits.  This is where things like CAS can be used as a lock, or you could use a locking record in the datastore.